# First Riddle Attempt

Tags: riddle, word, knowledge, language, affix-riddle

> My prefix is young.
> Is also a clipping.
> And will likely never have a crush.

> My suffix is well known and multiply defined in mathematics.
> It is defined in Geometry, Arithmetic operations, Group Theory and Topology.
> There is, to the best of my knowledge, at least one other important subfield of mathematics where it is defined.

> My whole is a French word which some fancy English typographers refer to.

---

I previously only posted puzzles on logic, math, optimization, chess and so on on puzzling.SE, this is my first attempt on riddle as I'm French and still learning English :)

#### Hint 11 10 2020

> You can see my whole in many of the world's addresses!

#### Hint 11 12 2020

> My first is a young word because it coined in the internet in the 2010s.

Comment: By first and second, I presume you mean prefix and suffix, right...?

Comment: @PrinceDeepthinker, yes indeed! Thank you for teaching me :)

Comment: Suffix has 2 fs

Comment: Also Why have you got a question inside the riddle? If it is not a clue then it really should be put as a bonus question.

Comment: @PrinceDeepthinker fixed for the fs :D I tried to replace the question :)

Comment: I think `knowledge` tag is perhaps more appropriate than `mathematics` tag, as the question doesn't really involve mathematical reasoning (see the description of the tag).

Comment: @WhatsUp, yes, thank you!

Comment: Can We have a hint?

Comment: @PrinceDeepthinker, sure!

Comment: Can I have another hint... maybe on the prefix. Still really have no idea.

Comment: @PrinceDeepthinker done :D, I'll try to give an hint every one or two day until someone finds :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the word is

> Arobase, aka the @ sign

> And will likely never have a crush.

> short for aromantic

> My prefix is young.

> As commented by @Stiv, aromantic has started being used in the 2010s

> Is also a clipping.

> As commented by @Stiv, aro is a clip of the full word

> My suffix is well known and multiply defined in mathematics.
> It is defined in Geometry, Arithmetic operations, Group Theory and Topology

> Triangle base, base n operations...

> You can see my whole in many of the world's addresses!

> Particularly in email addresses

> My whole is a French word which some fancy English typographers refer to.

> Arobase is the French word for @ and is probably used in typography

Comment: Nice spot :) Re 'young', the latest hint answers that for you, saying it was "coined in the internet in the 2010s". Re 'clipping', this might just be because it's an abbreviation, hence 'clipped'. Welcome to Puzzling!

Comment: @Stiv, thanks for shedding light on the missing bits :)